# Have the boys already finished the fight?

Tags: formality

Firstly, I'm Brazilian and this question may sound silly.

Imagine the following situation: two people arguing about a subject so that they are not reaching any agreement. They are not angry, but they have opposite opinions.

I being your friend, I try to make a joke of the situation by asking the following question:

"The boys have already finished the fight?"

My question would be if this phrase could be seen as a form of joke? Or there is another more objective phrase that is ironic but not aggressive.

Comment: Are you trying to tease them during their disagreement by calling it a fight? This may be a cultural question, but calling people boys and labeling their argument a fight is more suicidal than a joke should be.

Comment: You always should invert the subject and (auxiliary) verb to ask questions in English: *Have the boys already finished the fight?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common phrase to terminate to this type of situation would be "**agree to disagree?**" which can be phrased as a question or statement. However this is not really a joke.

What you suggested would probably work, and could be interpreted as a joke, but it's not something you hear much in every day American English.